# Cannot make a cache safe URL for "14/1033/styles/Themable/corev4.css", file not found. Please verify that the file exists under the layouts directory

Tags: windows, sharepoint

This is a 2013 Sharepoint Server.

Steps Taken

1) File exists in the following location
C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033\STYLES\corev4.css

C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033\STYLES\Themable\corev4.css

2) Language packs have been installed correctly

3) Incremental Crawl has been set to weekends only

4) IIS reset fixes the problem temporarily. After non business hours it appears again and continues until IIS reset.

Can any one help ?

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Please specify `Localizable = false` for the object. If it is Localizable then SharePoint will look for it in the LAYOUTS\1033\ folder else it will look for it in the LAYOUTS\ folder.